# Why the expected value, is not returned?

Tags: javascript

```js
function _Obj(arr) {
  if(arr.filter( cur => {
    return (cur instanceof Array)
  }).length === 0) {
    return  _assign(arr); // Here i try return the result
  } else {
    _Obj(Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arr));
  }

   function _assign(e) {
     var r = {};
     e.forEach((cur, index, arr) => {
       if(index%2 === 0 || index === 0) r[cur] = arr[index + 1];
     });
     console.log(r) // This is the result, this should be returned
     return r; // the result
   }
 }



var data = [
   [
    ['firstName', 'Joe'], 
    ['lastName', 'Blow'], 
    ['age', 42], 
    ['role', 'clerk']
   ]
];

console.log(_Obj(data));
```

I'm removing nested array, but the expected value (an array without an array inside), is NOT returned, but why? If what I'm returning is what the `_assign` function returns, then I know what I'm failing.

i need to return **the value of the function that returns** `_assign ()`, but it is not returned, also the result is correct and I check it with a `console.log ()`, so what is the error?

I do not mean the algorithm itself, i mean that the function `_Obj ()` should return the value returned by the `_assign ()` function, but it does not happen, why?

Comment: There is no reason to write `? true : false`.

Comment: Look at `Array.some()`.

Comment: `I'm removing concatenated array` what? Do you mean the `nested` arrays?

Comment: Yes @AngelPolitis, but, I do not mean the algorithm itself, i mean that the function _Obj () should return the value returned by the _assign () function, but it does not happen, why?

Comment: You should not use map() to do a loop. Use forEach if you need to iterate over the array.

Comment: Unrelated to the question: `() => { return expression }` is the same as `() => expression`.

Comment: Also: `_assign` is redefined every time you call `_Obj`, consider moving it outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of [@Mt. Schneiders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48009607/6313073) pretty much covers the main reason that your code fails.

Simply put, if you don't return the intermediary values gotten in each iteration of the recursive function those values are lost.

The following pseudocode resembles how the recursive function works for the given example and should help clear things out on why your issue occurs:

```
_Obj [
    _Obj [
       return _assign
    ]
]
```

In the above, the function `_Obj` calls `_Obj` which in turn calls the function `_assign`. Since the value of `_assign` is returned, the value of the inner `_Obj` is now equal to that. The value of the outer `_Obj`, however, is `undefined`, because the inner `_Obj` didn't return anything.

In order for `_Obj` to function as expected, the pseudocode should be as follows:

```
_Obj [
    return _Obj [
       return _assign
    ]
]
```

Now, since the value of the inner `_Obj` is returned, the final value logged to the console is the value of `_assign`.

Below, I provide a cleaner, more legible version of the correct code.

**Snippet:**

```js
function _assign (array) {
  /* Create an object. */
  var object = {};

  /* Iteratew over every element in the array. */
  array.forEach(function(element, index) {
    /* Check if the index is even. */
    if (index % 2 == 0) object[element] = array[index + 1];
  });

  /* Return the object. */
  return object;
}

function _Obj(array) {
  /* Filter the array. */
  var filtered = array.filter(current => current instanceof Array);

  /* Call either _assign or _Obj and return its value. */
  return (filtered.length === 0) ? _assign(array) : _Obj([].concat.apply([], array));
}


/* Example. */
console.log(_Obj([
  [
    ['firstName', 'Joe'],
    ['lastName', 'Blow'],
    ['age', 42],
    ['role', 'clerk']
  ]
]));
```

**Notes:**

1. Since `0 % 2 = 0`, using `if (index % 2 === 0 || index === 0)` is redundant. Just using
   `if (index % 2 == 0)` will suffice.
2. You had better define `_assign` outside `_Obj`, because, by virtue of the way your code is currently structured, `_assign` is defined again and again on each call of `_Obj`.
3. Using `cur => { return (cur instanceof Array) }` is unnecessarily verbose. You can write `cur => cur instanceof Array` instead.

Comment: Thanks @Mt.Schneiders! +1 on your answer from me as well; after all, I used it as reference. I'm pretty sure that our combined effort will drive the point home, regarding the importance of `return`.

Answer (score 1):

The current flow is as follows:

1. `_Obj` is called
2. `_Obj` calls itself
3. `_Obj` calls _assign
4. `_assign` returns the value
5. `_Obj` returns the value returned by `_assign`
6. `_Obj` doesn't return the value returned by `_Obj` (value is lost here)

Therefore, you should add a return there as well.

Example:

```js
function _Obj(arr) {
  if(arr.filter( function(cur) {
    return (cur instanceof Array)
  }).length === 0) {
    return  _assign(arr);
  } else {
    return _Obj(Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arr)); //Must return here also
  }

   function _assign(e) {
     var r = {};
     e.forEach(function(cur, index, arr) {
       if(index%2 === 0 || index === 0) r[cur] = arr[index + 1];
     });
     return r;
   }
 }

var data = [
   [
    ['firstName', 'Joe'], 
    ['lastName', 'Blow'], 
    ['age', 42], 
    ['role', 'clerk']
   ]
];

console.log(_Obj(data));
```

Comment: Care to explain what was wrong? IE why is that return statement needed?

Comment: It works fine, but why? , why do I need to return the value, if I just want to call it and in the base case return?

Comment: If you don't return it, the value gotten inside the recursive function will be lost @carlos.

Comment: @Angel Politis, Exactly.

Comment: If the value is lost, then how did you get to the base case? and also if it is lost, how then, the _assign () function can make use of this "lost" value?

Comment: The only thing I do not understand now, is why you must return the value, yes in the control flow, when _assign () returns its value, the function _Obj () gets that value, and returns it. And that's where the function ends and it does not enter the "else" condition, so why should I add a return, if it will not even get there? ,

Comment: Give a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48009664/6313073) @carloscerdadiaz. I have created a little "graph" to illustrate why `return` is necessary.